# 18.04: Numeric keypad doesn't work on my MSI GF75

Tags: 18.04, msi

The numeric keypad doesn't work on my [MSI GF75 thin](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GF75-Thin-8RX/Specification) laptop. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

How can I troubleshoot this to enable the numeric keypad?

Comment: 1) Did it work with any other operating system (e.g., Windows)? 2) If you haven't tested that, please make a LiveUSB from another Ubuntu flavor, temporarily boot with it, and test. download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions in your Ubuntu 18.04  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

Comment: It works perfectly on my windows 10 . I have a dual boot system . Also in my boot live USB doesn't work as far I remember.  Two days ago I was working on the live version .